# Graphics driver problem

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, ati

I have a **AMD/ATI HD6600**.

I have already tested every single popular Linux distribution and I still have this problem. If I start using non-proprietary drivers, most of the time I start my PC after grub I get a black screen, then I have to press `ctrl + alt + F1` and then `ctrl + alt + del` to reboot, luckily it will work next reboot, when it does, I cant even suspend my laptop.

Ok, let's use proprietary drivers... everything works perfect, except for Screen bright function and GUI becomes laggy.

When I reboot using a live USB drive, everything works fine, I will always boot well and everything works smooth. Is there a way to tell Ubuntu to use that standard live Ubuntu uses?

Every answer and tips are welcome. Thank you so much!